# Quotes in CSS selectors

Tags: css

Which of the CSS selectors below would you prefer? (note using quotes)

```
[class*=col-] {   /* all classes that contain 'col' */
    ...
}
```

```
[class*='col-'] { /* all classes that contain 'col' */
    ...
}
```

```
[class*="col-"] { /* all classes that contain 'col' */
    ...
}
```

Comment: Actually, a duplicate of [CSS attribute selectors: The rules on quotes (", ' or none?)](/questions/5578845/css-attribute-selectors-the-rules-on-quotes-or-none)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can leave it unquoted if it's alphanumeric, as long as it doesn't contain ", ', `, =, <, or >.

From the HTML spec:

> Attributes are placed inside the start tag, and consist of a name and a value, separated by an "=" character. The attribute value can remain unquoted if it doesn't contain space characters or any of " ' ` = < or >. Otherwise, it has to be quoted using either single or double quotes. The value, along with the "=" character, can be omitted altogether if the value is the empty string.

For consistency I prefer double quotes. No point in using them only sometimes - that makes for messy and less readable code.

Answer (score 1):

You can check out this interesting [Unquoted attribute values in HTML and CSS/JS selectors](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/unquoted-attribute-values)

> after cross-referencing these three different sections of the HTML
>   spec, we can finally conclude that a valid unquoted attribute value in
>   HTML is any string of text that is not the empty string and that
>   doesn’t contain spaces, tabs, line feeds, form feeds, carriage
>   returns, ", ', `, =, <, or >.

You can omit the quotes if the attribute value is alphanumeric(but do check the exception in the above article)

Answer (score 1):

```
[class*=col-] {   /* all classes that contain 'col' */
    ...
}
```

`[class*=col-]` is used to find where the element(within the tag) contains the class attribute value with the col- string.